# Excel BBG formulas not refreshing

Tags: excel, vba, refresh, bloomberg

I am trying to write a basic script to open another file, refresh the data in that file, save that updated file off as values (not formulae), and then closes the originally opened file containing the formulas without saving. My issue is that the file doesn't actually pull the requested formulae until after the macro has finished and the 'updated' file has saved itself away. In other words the formulae start to refresh, apparently never finish refreshing, and then copy/paste over themselves with the "#N/A Requesting Data..." string, instead of the actual data. I've seen a number of simlar questions around about this, but I haven't seen one which defines why the issue exists in the first place. I have tried runnign the refresh and the saving in different subs, and have tried a number of different methos of waiting for the formulae to finish refreshing, without avail. E.g.:

```
'ATTEMPT 1
'Application.Calculate
'If Not Application.CalculationState = xlDone Then
'   DoEvents
'End If

'ATTEMPT 2
'Do: DoEvents: Loop While Application.CalculationState = xlCalculating

'ATTEMPT 3
'Do Until ActiveSheet.CalculationState = xlDone
'   DoEvents
'Loop
```

Here is the code which runs once the initiating file is openend:

```
Sub Auto_Open()

Call Refresh

'COPY PASTE VALUES
ActiveSheet.Cells.Copy

'COPY UPDATED SHEET TO NEW BOOK & SAVE AS .XLS
Workbooks.Add
With ActiveSheet
.Cells.PasteSpecial xlValues
.Cells.PasteSpecial xlFormats
End With
Application.CutCopyMode = False
ActiveWorkbook.SaveAs (NewBook & Format(Now(), "DD-MMM-YYYY hh mm AMPM") & ".xls")


End Sub
```

Here is the sub which actually refreshes the data:

```
Sub Refresh()
```

Application.Calculation = xlCalculationManual 'ENSURE IT ONLY PULLS DATA WHEN YOU TELL IT TO

```
Dim wkbook As Workbook
Dim OpenedBook As String
OpenedBook = "G:\Folder Name\Sub Folder\File Opened in Folder.xlsx" 'FULL PATH OF WORKBOOK TO BE OPENED
NewBook = "G:\Folder Name\Sub Folder\File Saved in Folder\" 'BASE NAME OF THE SAVED WORKBOOK

'OPEN THE DESIRED WORKBOOK
Set wkbook = Workbooks.Open(OpenedBook)
wkbook.Activate

'REFRESH ALL BBG FORMULAE
Application.Run "RefreshAllWorkbooks"
Application.Run "RefreshAllStaticData"
Application.Wait (Now + TimeValue("00:00:10"))


End Sub
```

The actual formula being refreshed work otherwise, and are straighforward BBG BDH formulae. E.g. =BDP(B3&" curncy", "px_mid") where B3 has a currency pair like "EURUSD". Any thoughts on why the formulae are not pulling, even after the Wait and DoEvents 'fixes'? I have a feleing I am misunderstanding something fundamental about how BBG/VBA works, so please help me understand why this situation exists in the first place. Thanks in advance!

Comment: Set the calc state to manual. Then calc the sheet with the BBG formulas. Then Copy the values, or user a `Application.Wait` statement that is longer than 10 seconds. Sometimes these third party plug-ins can be tough to deal with.

Comment: @ScottHoltzman  - this somewhat worked. Now the file pulls and saves, but the template file which has the live formulae now doesn't actually stays showing "#N/A Requesting Data." So now the file saved off is good, but the original is not. Oddly, when I type a new BBG formula into that same sheet, the new formula pulls properly, although the others that refreshed when I ran the macro do not. Is this some symptom of using Application.Calculation = xlCalculationManual? If I have multiple workbooks open I imagine this will create problems. Can I not only refresh the formulae in the template file?

Comment: @ScottHoltzman - turns out your suggestion did not actually work. The template file with all the formulae does not actually update and save off properly. The version that saves off doesn't pull new data - instead it copies of the same data points that were present in the file when it last saved. In other words it is like the copy of it is a copy of the file BEFORE the formulae refresh... so now I seem further from the goal. The formulas don't seem to engage in pulling new points before they're copied and saved off! The only change I made to my code was to unhide the Application.Calculate line.

Comment: I'm sorry this is so difficult. I can't be of any more help because I have nothing to test with since I don't have bloomberg plug-in. That said, I feel you're pain because I've been through it and seen it in the past as well.